# How to make MPChart not display value for selected labels

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPchart android Lib Line Graph. In the image attached I do not want to display the last 2 labels value, but the labels should be displayed. 
Below is the code written to customize the graph:

```
    mSetingsGraph.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(true);
    mSetingsGraph.getAxisRight().setEnabled(true);
    mSetingsGraph.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(true);
    mSetingsGraph.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
    mSetingsGraph.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
    mSetingsGraph.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(true);
    mSetingsGraph.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(true);
    mSetingsGraph.setScaleMinima(0.0f, 0f);
    mSetingsGraph.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
    mSetingsGraph.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    mSetingsGraph.setTouchEnabled(false);
    mSetingsGraph.setDragEnabled(false);
    mSetingsGraph.setScaleEnabled(false);
    mSetingsGraph.setPinchZoom(false);
    mSetingsGraph.setHardwareAccelerationEnabled(true);
```

Code line used to set value is `values.add(new Entry(j, value));`

I tried setting value to negative values but it dint work. How can I achieve this ?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you set you values to 0 then ?